# reshape 2d list

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to implement this function but I'm not sure exactly how to do so. I know we have to use a for loop for this problem but as with setting with variables and such, or if it contains a nested for loop, I am unsure.

```
def reshape(thelist, rows, cols):
    """Returns: A rows*cols 2D list with the contents of thelist

    Hint:  In a 2D list, the element at row x and col y is the
    x*cols+y element listed.

    Example: reshape([1,2,3,4],2,2) returns [[1,2], [3,4]]
    Example: reshape([1,2,3,4,5,6],3,2) returns [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
    Example: reshape([1,2,3,4,5,6],2,3) returns [[1,2,3] ,[4,5,6]]

    Precondition: thelist is a list of numbers of size rows*cols. rows
    and cols are positive integers."""
```

Comment: Why don't you try one way and show where you have a problem instead? There isn't only one possible answer for a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def reshape(thelist, rows,cols):  
    parent_list = []
    count = 0
    for j in range(rows):
        new_list = []
        for i in range(cols):
            new_list.append(thelist[count])
            count+=1
        parent_list.append(new_list)
    return parent_list
```

Comment: This can be done without nesting loops but this method is more clear and easy to understand for a beginner.

Answer (score 1):

See [What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/434287/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-iterate-over-a-list-in-chunks):

```
def reshape(thelist, rows,cols):  
    return [thelist[i:i + cols] for i in range(0, len(thelist), cols)]
```

If you don't need to preserve types, you could also write it as `zip(*[iter(thelist)]*cols)`. See the explanation in the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I could think of is this:

```
def thesplit(input_list, rows, cols):
    output_list = []
    for i in range(rows):
        pos = i*cols
        output_list.append(input_list[pos:pos+cols])
    return output_list
```

If you do not want the variable pos, you can use this instead:

```
output_list.append(input_list[(i*pos):((i+1)*pos)])
```

which is same as that of the previous sample.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an expansion of J.F. Sebastian's 2nd solution:

```
def reshape(seq, rows, cols):
    return [list(u) for u in zip(*[iter(seq)] * cols)]

rows, cols = 3, 4
seq = range(rows * cols)
print reshape(seq, rows, cols)
```

**output**

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]
```

I initially found this algorithm a little puzzling. The key to understanding how it works is to realize that `[iter(seq)] * cols` creates a list of `cols` references to the *same* iterator *not* `cols` independent iterators. So each time `zip` pulls a value from one of the entries it effectively gets the next entry from the original list. And so another way to write essentially the same algorithm is:

```
def reshape(seq, rows, cols):
    g = iter(seq)
    return [[g.next() for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
```